# Can I completely avoid becoming a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I do not want to have to become a werewolf, but seeing where it is necessary to continue on with the Companion quest lines, at least some of them.

I was told to talk with Skjor, so it is on my "quest" page now, but; could I not just ignore all the quest and the Companions completely from this point on out? It won't have a negative bearing on the main objective of the game will it? Or on any other factions in the game? I have not seen where it goes into this detail, not on the USEPWiki pages or these or anywhere I can find?  Will you be able to do most of the quest in the game still?  How valuable is it to even finish this?  It is not a required faction in how the game ends right?

I am on xbox 360, version 1.00.4 I believe.

Comment: Do you just want to know if you need to become a werewolf to beat the game?

Comment: I suggested reviewing your question as i'm finding it hard to understand it, also i see a lot of question marks and an apology for asking so many questions, make sure all your questions are related to much less the same thing

Comment: Thank you for the laugh. I'd been having a bad day! :) It is much appreciated!?

Answer (score 6):

The Companion quest-line is a side-quest, so it is non-essential to the plot line. For the sake of completion, you get a title, and a pretty nifty axe if you want it, and every time after when you visit Jorrvaskr everyone knows your name ([reminds me of an old sitcom...](http://youtu.be/rS0VQOHX7lM))

However, there are ways to cure the Werewolf curse, which is actually part of the Companion's quest line. And if you got the Dawnguard DLC, you can choose to become another mythical creature, which will override the werewolf curse, however, curing that can be a bit trickier.

Comment: I'd also mention "Nord Hero Arrows".  The main reason *I* finish the Companion's quest line.  Turn those rusted Steel quality things you find in crypts into Elven quality arrows.  This is only available at the Skyforge after talking to Eorlund after Kodlak's fureral.

Answer (score 1):

You asked a few questions so I will answer them all.

1. The Companions storyline is a completely separate one from the main quest, so deciding to not finish the companions storyline and not becoming a werewolf will not stop you from completing the main quest, nor will it have a negative effect on the main quest.
2. Being a werewolf and/or being part of the companions will not interfere with any other guilds you have joined, they are all separate parts of the game.
3. If you are a werewolf you can still complete all of the other quests.
4. As Ben said, you will get a title and cool axe for completing the quest-line.

I hope this answers all of your questions.